# How to enforce garbage collector to call finalize method first, before cleaning up reference of unused objects

Tags: java, c, garbage-collection

I have a scenario which uses a C library using JNA:
I have override the finalize method where I send the call to delete the object that is created through C.
My code looks somewhat like this:

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
    {
        if (LicensingAPIHelper.instance == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("LicensingAPIHelper is not initialized");
                   LicensingAPIHelper.instance.sntl_licensing_app_context_delete(nativeAppContext.getValue());
    }
```

`sntl_licensing_app_context_delete` is the API, which deletes the object created in the C library.
`nativeAppContext` is PointerByReference and `nativeAppContext.getValue()` sends the pointer of the object to be deleted.
What is happening right now is, when GC is called a crash occurs because the `nativeAppContext` reference is cleaned first by GC and since it does not find any reference so when it tries to get the value for sending to C library it crashes.

Is there any way to enforce GC to call finalize method first before cleaning up the objects?

In this case, I assume GC cleans up the object first and then calls the `finalize` method.

Comment: No I don't think you can. You probably need a more manual cleanup process.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the GC calls `finalize` *before* destroying the object... (Otherwise, there wouldn't be an object to call finalize on...)

Comment: I was also under same impression that GC calls finalize first, but when I check the reference value before sending call to C library, thats null. So I assumed GC must have cleaned the object and so the reference is null.

Comment: I've done exactly what you claim doesn't work: used the `finalize()` method as an occasion to delete the associated C++ object. But I was holding the C++ pointer as a`long` in the current class. You seem to be putting your finalizer in the wrong class.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, thats what I want to know, if I am doing something wrong. I have put finalie() method in everyclass. and called the delete API from finalize method, so when the objects gets out of scope finalize() is called and associated C object gets deleted. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You need to put the finalizer in the class that owns the C object. Not the class that owns that class that owns the C object. An object reference can be nulled by GC, but a `long` can't be.

Comment: Yes I have put the finalize() in the same class which owns the C object. Its not working.

Comment: "It's not working" how? You can't still be getting the problem described in this question, because you can no longer have a `null` to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

It is and it is only guaranteed that the finalize() method is called before the object is cleaned by the GC.

What you are trying to do is just not what finalize() is made for. I never known when the GC will clean up the instance you used. It's not like a descructor in C++. It will not immediatelly be called after a variable gets out of scope. Therefore using finalize() for your cleanup code will hold open your C library for much more time then needed.

What you are looking for is probably the close() method of the interfaces `java.io.Closeable` or `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.

Instead of putting your code in the finalize() method but it in there and mark your class `implements AutoCloseable`. Then when you construct your instance of your class use a try-with-resouces block. When this block gets exited, the `close()`-method will be called automatically.

```
try (MyClass myInstance = new MyClass()) {
    // use myInstance here
}
// myInstance.close() will have been called here automatically
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Closeable and AutoCloseable is introduced in java7. What about java 6 users? How can they achieve this? I have 1 query as well: So you are trying to say , I can't call native library API in finalize() method. right? Becoz if finalize() is called immediately after a variable gets out of scope then the first call in fainalize() is call to C library to delete object, that would have been called, but that's not happening. So is it that any API call to third library canot be done through finalize() method?

Comment: finalize() is just NOT called immediately after a variable gets out of scope. This is by design of Java. If you still need to support old versions of Java, the way to go is to implement it as a close() method anyway but you have to call this close() method your self always before your variable gets out of scope. There is no automatism for this on Java up to version 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This means I need to call this delete API of C mannually. Thanks again!